# How to enable/disable specific radiogroupbuttons in shiny, shinyjs, shinywidget

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a set of groupradiobuttons, and I would like to have control over which specific buttons a user is allowed to press - without having to make them all separate radio buttons and not simply disabling the whole group. E.g., in the case below, I have made it so that when you select an option other than 'None' from the 'disabler' selectinput, it disables all the buttons. But I would like to know how to make it so that the specific selection of what to enable/disable can specifically enable/disable a specific one of the radio buttons. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  selectInput("disabler",
              label = "Choose button to disable",
              choices = c("None", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")),
  
  radioGroupButtons("buttons",
                             label = "Here are the buttons:",
                             selected = "1",
                             choiceNames = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                             choiceValues = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                             individual = FALSE)
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$disabler, {
    if(input$disabler == "None") {
      shinyjs::enable("buttons")
    } 
    else if(input$disabler != "None") {
      shinyjs::disable("buttons")
    }
  })
   
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733147/unable-to-disable-a-shiny-app-radio-button-using-shinyjs

Comment: Thank you @sckraa this helped me to disable them buttons individually - I will just have to work out cleanly how to re-enable them all in a similar way afterwards. I will post the code once it works!